# How to keep in sync angular with its azure(asp.net core) backend?

Tags: angular, azure

I've already done a few Angular applications with firebase as hosting/backend. Now for one project, I've to do the same with Azure.

With firebase, there was a package(angularfire) which was allowing me to easily access the database, and more importantly in my case, keeping them in sync: If one user add one item, I need the others users to see it directly.

I can't find an equivalent on Azure, so I guess that I've to write web API to retrieve my differents elements, but this won't work, I will only get the status at a specific time. And polling seems overkill.

So, my question in the end: How am I supposed to keep in sync one collection of Azure with one angular SPA?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such a thing on Azure. What you can do is use Azure Cosmos Db as your database and use it's Change feed to track what is new/updated. Then, use an Azure Functions + Azure Signalr Service to push those items to your front end using WebSockets

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question is incomplete. It's planned to use Azure Cosmo Db. I'm unaware of azure SignalR, I will search to see if I can see how to integrate this with angular

Comment: you'll need some backend code which will be Azure Functions part which will send the updates to your front end

Comment: Okay, I found this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/real-time-angular-8-application-with-signalr-and-cosmos-db/ But this seems to mean that I've to manage myself everything(what is inside the update), conflicts, when I'm offline/online, ... There is really nothing better from azure? I'm quite surprised :'(